# Set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in toolchain.cmake

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I have a `toolchain.cmake` defined for the platform I'm building for and in it I've specified the location where I want my files installed.  However, when I run `make install`, the files go to the default location `/usr/....`.  My `toolchain.cmake` is setup as follows:

```
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/bin/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/bin/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu-g++)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot)
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
SET(THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG 1)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/local/include)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/local/lib)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_MANDIR /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot/share/man)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot)
SET(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot)
```

As can be seen, I've gone overkill on setting paths, but none of them work.  In order to have `make install` place the file in the correct location, I have to pass `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>` in the cmake command as shown below:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/myScripts/Toolchain-Naoqi.2.1.4.13.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-mac64/ctc-mac64-atom-2.1.4.13/cross/i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu/sysroot ..
```

It would be nice not to have the path set in my `toolchain.cmake` as it applies to all the projects I'm building.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your paths are overwritten is that the call to `project()` comes after the execution of this Toolchain file. The `project()` function, among other things, sets `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to some default value.

It is good practice **not** to specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, to ensure cross-platform compatibility. For example, your approach would prevent someone with a non-Unix-like system of using your file.

If you really want to go on and specify it within the code, I see two options:

- Hardcode `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in one of the `CMakeLists.txt` of your project, i.e. *after* the call to `project()`.
- Provide a custom 'platform' file, located in `some_folder/Platform/<My_Platform>.cmake`, and add `some_folder` to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. In this platform file, you then specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, such that you don't need to clobber your other `CMakeLists.txt` (my assumption here is that you only need this installation folder for this specific platform).

Comment: Nibor, thanks for the info, but you've misunderstood some of what I'm doing.  I am not specifying the`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in the CMakelist.txt file.  I want to set it in the toolchain, which will be applicable for all cases that I'm building for a specific platform because the staging area will be the same for all of them.  Someone with a non-Unix-like system would use a different toolchain.cmake definition.
I will try applying the advise in your second point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue is caused by a bug in CMake itself, based on an old [bug report](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12600) in their former bug tracker, which was closed without fixing the problem.

The issue is summarised as

> Specifying CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in a CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE file has no
>   effect

which exactly describes the problem you are encountering.

For what it's worth, I also encounter this same problem when trying to cross-compile with CMake v3.5.1 using a toolchain file, so I don't think that the issue has been fixed.

The migrated bug report in CMake's current bug tracker may be found [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12600).

Besides the workaround you  have identified involving setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inline in the install command, a more permanent solution might be reached by petitioning the CMake team to fix this bug, by adding your comments to the conversation in the migrated bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old. But since I also stumbled over this issue recently. I thought it my be helpful for others to answer it:

According to this [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux). `CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX` should be used instead of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. At least for me it seemed to work.